# intellij doesn't pick Ivy dependencies at deployment

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am trying to deploy a web app on intellij, when creating the exploded directory some ivy dependencies/spring aren't picked up in the exploded directory!!

Can someone help me with this error I spent a lot of time trying to resolve the dependencies but nothing works.

My configuration is :

health_monitor.repeat_interval=60000
roll_call.repeat_interval=30000

in files : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86wn7.jpg)

Stack :

```
    XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.config.IntervalTask#1' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
            at 
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:546)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:517)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
            at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"
            at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
            at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:209)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitIndexedArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:150)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:84)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:206)
            ... 36 more
        INFO  01/31 09:42:00.230 {} [ServerService Thread Pool -- 79] DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@48cca427: defining beans [mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,freemarkerConfig,avFreeMarkerConfig,viewResolver,com.bfm.aps.util.PropertiesUtil#0,com.bfm.aps.util.PropertiesUtil#1,com.bfm.aps.util.PropertiesUtil#2,com.bfm.aps.util.PropertiesUtil$PropertiesDumper#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,com.bfm.aps.util.AutowireUtil#0,com.bfm.aps.service.util.ContextLoggerAspect#0,com.bfm.aps.service.util.InstantiationTracer#0,com.bfm.app.aladdinsearch.service.upload.impl.LightWeightUploadServiceImpl#0,connectionAgent,metadataServerDecodesMapLoader,decodes-org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@8bef7c
        ERROR 01/31 09:42:00.230 {} [ServerService Thread Pool -- 79] DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.config.IntervalTask#1' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:223)
            at com.bfm.aps.util.PropertiesUtil.processProperties(PropertiesUtil.java:52)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:696)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"
            at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
            at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:209)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitIndexedArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:150)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:84)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:206)
            ... 36 more
        09:42:00,231 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./AladdinSearch_war_exploded: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./AladdinSearch_war_exploded: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.config.IntervalTask#1' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.config.IntervalTask#1' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:223)
            at com.bfm.aps.util.PropertiesUtil.processProperties(PropertiesUtil.java:52)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:696)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:546)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:517)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
            at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
            at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
            at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
            at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
            ... 6 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value "${roll_call.repeat_interval}"
            at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
            at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)


        09:42:00,236 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "AladdinSearch_war_exploded")]) - failure description: {
            "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./AladdinSearch_war_exploded" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./AladdinSearch_war_exploded: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.config.IntervalTask#1' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value \"${roll_call.repeat_interval}\"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value \"${roll_call.repeat_interval}\"
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.config.IntervalTask#1' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value \"${roll_call.repeat_interval}\"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value \"${roll_call.repeat_interval}\"
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'roll_call.repeat_interval' in string value \"${roll_call.repeat_interval}\""},
            "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./AladdinSearch_war_exploded"],
            "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
        }
        09:42:00,237 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "AladdinSearch_war_exploded.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
        {

            "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
```

I know the error is with : roll_call.repeat_interval I tried to hard code the value  but other dependencies are missing and it keeps on and on so my guess it is not copied to the exploded directory Although I added the spring facet to the project from modules  :

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="rollCallService" method="getHealthUpdate" fixed-delay="${roll_call.repeat_interval}" initial-delay="3000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Comment: When resolving spring dependencies manually : I got the error :
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bfm.app.aladdinsearch.servlet.impl.PluginStaticResourceServlet
which is an ivy dependency.
[org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry apache-cassandra-thrift-1.0.10.jar in path/Aldintrunck/classes/artifacts/AladdinSearch_war_exploded/WEB-INF/lib/apache-cassandra-1.0.10-1.0.10.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
... and other missing jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly : I was missing one Configuration file adding this one to the Vm Arguments of server configuration did the trick.